# A* algorithm with euclidean distance

Tags: algorithm, a-star

If I have a set of nodes with coordinates (x, y) and I have a set of node - node - cost, in this case the cost is in minute. How do I calculate the Euclidean distance assuming the **speed is constant**...

One metric is in minutes and while the distance using x,y is not in time metric

Comment: Are you asking what [the Euclidean distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions) is?

Comment: Are points that are further from each other (in euclidean terms) have an edge with a greater cost in minutes than those closer together?

Comment: I am asking how to consider the different metrics of time (minutes) and distance of coordinates to calculate a euclidean distance.. because they both need to have the same unit.. I know what the formula is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally recommend [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm). It taught me how to implement A* in a game I made a few years back.

Also, the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) page is always good for linking! :)

Comment: I have read the wikipedia page like 10 times and I know how the algorithm works. It's just that different units of cost and the coordinates conflicts is what I am confused with.

Comment: If your metric is time, but your speed is constant, you can just use distance to target as your metric. They're equivalent since Distance = Velocity * Time.

Comment: well, the time is proportional to distance so they're interchangeable. And a* works with distance by default in that tutorial so just work through it and it should be fine :)

Comment: I understand it is proportional, but this distance might be in feet and then that coordinate distance might be in units.. might have to do some conversion

Comment: no, the conversion from feet to any other distance measurement should also be linear (proportional). So they're freely swappable